# How do I remove page numbers using revtex

Tags: page-numbering, revtex

I am writing my physics thesis in LaTex for the first time, using RevTex (APS) style formatting (code below). Unfortunately, the department is compiling all of the majors' papers into a single booklet. Therefore, they want us all to remove the page numbers from our individual documents. How do I do this, using the document class template they provided (shown below)?

```
\documentclass[aps,prd,floatfix,nofootinbib,twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4):

One way is to add `\pagestyle{empty}`.

```
\documentclass[aps,prd,floatfix,nofootinbib,twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! I think that's going to work. I tested it out, and it took out the page numbers. Thanks for your help : )

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: @Nicole, by clicking on the check mark.